# how to uninstall gcc and all its related libraries?

Tags: gcc, uninstallation, gmp, mpfr

I am running really low on memory on my development machine. I was looking to explore gdb with xcode projects but then i realized it already had lldb preinstalled.

In short, i did installation for gcc-

```
  brew install gcc
```

and it completed installing gmp, mpfr,limpc,isl and half way through gcc when I ctrl+c the process.

Any suggestions on how to remove all the above without causing any problems to other dependencies that might exist in the system?

i really don't need it, just wanted to explore gdb with xcode projects.

Also, I dont know where exactly have these components scattered during the installation, I know uninstall option does not exist, so I might have to go and delete each component in all the directories.

I have up till now done a-

```
  find / -name gcc
```

and deleted gcc at those locations, cannot however find gmp, mpfr, etc

Comment: You don't even say **how** you installed gcc...

Comment: @MarcGlisse

I have edited the question, forgot about it, sorry! Please let me know if you have some suggestions!

Thank you!